# How to pass data with custom object types between tasks in Airflow

Tags: airflow

I am new to Airflow and my use case is to read data from one system via an API, then read data from a 2nd system via API by using a python module and then compare the data and make updates to the the 2nd system via the API.
I am using a python module for the 2nd system that stores the data in custom object models. Those custom models handle the API calls in the background for me in case I make update and use the .save() function for an object.

So the question is how to pass the data from one task. to another and where to import the module.

Comment: You may want to check either xcoms: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/xcoms.html, either airflow variables: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/variable.html

Comment: I in order to use xcom or airflow variables you need to have standard datatypes like list, string int etc. I doubt it will work with custom models. I assume that the data needs to be convert able into json string as they use celery in the backend to pass the data to the workers.

Answer (score 2):

Passing data between tasks is always using `Xcoms` which is actually a Python dictionary.

more information can be found here-
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/xcoms.html

Using the `TaskFlow` API of Airflow, can provide some abstraction.

example:

```
@dag()
def example():
   @task()
   def get_exterior_data():
      res = some_api_call()
      return {"exterior_data":res}

   @task()
   def use_exterior_data(params: dict):
      data = params['exterior_data']

  params = get_exterior_data()
  use_exterior_data(params)

example()
```

Notice you can use a complex structure (e.g dataclass), but it must be JSON serializable.